# ERROR:relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Py_NoneStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: gcc, makefile, omnet++, lld

I am getting a make error while running omnetpp.

I have turned the clang and the lld off. The exact error is:

Creating shared library: /home/ash/omnetpp-master/out/gcc-release/src/sim/liboppsim.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.10.a(pythonrun.o): warning: relocation against `_Py_UnhandledKeyboardInterrupt' in read-only section` .text'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.10.a(bytearrayobject.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Py_NoneStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:135: /home/ash/omnetpp-master/out/gcc-release/src/sim/liboppsim.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:134: sim] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:35: allmodes] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use the omnetpp master branch. There is absolutely no guarantee that the master branch is properly working or at least compiling at any given time.